# How to call a method from same class in another method in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, static-methods

Now I am working with c# code that looks something like this

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void Method1()
    {
        //Do something
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        //Do something
        Method1();
    }
}
```

Now what if I replace the code as:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void Method1()
    {
        //Do something
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        //Do something
        MyClass.Method1();
    }
}
```

Now what is the difference in above 2 representations.
Is it the same or does it show some different working.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The only difference is readability. In the second code snippet you know just by looking at `MyClass.Method1();` that it's a static method. In the first one you have to check.

Comment: It can be considered same as calling an obvious class field or property in class method with `this.` identifier. The only difference it would make for you is readability when you have another class having a static method with same name. You can differentiate those two methods with class name.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second is just a longer version of the previous. If you are in the same class as the static method, you do not need to specify the class name, you can, but you don't need to (much like specifying `this` for instance methods).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Had a lot of confusion as some place it was used as 1st representation and some place as 2nd. Hence I started wondering if their working was different.

Comment: @JasmeetsinghBansal It is a good idea to pick one version and stick with it, I prefer the more verbose version (`MyClass.Method1()`) as it is more clear just by looking at the code that you are talking about a static method

Answer (score 1):

Inside the class there is no difference but the difference comes when you try to invoke them from outside the class. For instance method you need a instance of your class whereas for static method that's not required. But inside your class you can just say

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void Method1()
    {
        //Do something
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        Method1();  //you don't have to qualify it
    }
}
```